# How to give value of string to another string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, math, if-statement

**I have a simple question. I want to calculate training heart rate.And I have some values. RHR means that resting heart rate. INTEN means fitnes level and I give values 0.55,0.65,0.8 for low, medium and high fitness level I wrote that code**

```
 Gender=input('Please input your gender: ');
 Age=input('Please input your age: ');
 RHR=input('Please enter your resting heart rate: ');
 INTEN=input('Please enter your fitness level(low,medium or high): ');
 male=Male;
 female=Female;
 low=0.55;
 medium=0.65;
 high=0.8;
 if INTEN==0.55
 INTENT=0.55;
 elseif INTENT==medium
INTENT=0.65;
else 
INTENT=0.8;
end
 if Gender==Male
 THR=((220-Age)-RHR)*INTEN+RHR;
 elseif Gender==Female
 THR=((206-0.88*Age)-RHR)*INTEN+RHR;
 end
  disp('The recommended training heart rate is ',num2str(THR))
```

**But it gave error why?**

Comment: Indent your code properly, show the test case, and show the error.

Comment: What is `Male` and `Female`?

Comment: I want to give another variable to work

Comment: Please input your gender: male
Error using input
Undefined function or variable 'male'.

Error in Experiment3 (line 2)
Gender=input('Please input your gender: ');

Comment: Assign a string like so `male ='Male'`

Comment: Test string equality with `strcmp(Gender,Male)`

Comment: Specify string input with `input(blablabla,'s')`

Comment: @TryHard - Took the words right out of my mouth!

Comment: And read/search the documentation with `help blablablafunction`!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code. Notably you are using operations reserved to compare numbers with strings, which is not possible. Moreover, the variable `Gender` should be a string but is manipulated as a number, which is confusing. Be sure to look into the function [strcmp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html?searchHighlight=strcmp) that is used to compare strings together. You can then use `if/elseif` blocks.

I propose using a `prompt` to query the informations from the user. That way everything is displayed at the same time and is in my opinion much simpler to work with.

Here is the code with comments. If something is unclear please tell me.

```
clc
clear

%// Set up dialog promt.
prompt = {'Enter your gender (male/female)','Enter your age:','Enter your resting heart rate: ','Enter your fitness level(low,medium or high): '};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;

%// Default answers
def = {'male','30','120','medium'};

%// The answers are stored in the cell array called "answer". Its a 4x1
%// cell array containing ONLY STRINGS.
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);

%// Transform the strings into numbers that you can use.
Gender = answer{1};
Age = str2double(answer{2});
RHR = str2double(answer{3});
INTEN = answer{4};

%// A switch/case statement to convert INTEN into the number used for
%// the calculation
switch INTEN
    case 'low'
        INTEN=0.55;
    case 'medium'
         INTEN=0.65;
    case 'high'
        INTEN=0.8;
end

%// Use strcmp to compare strings. 
if strcmp(Gender,'Male') || strcmp(Gender,'male')

    THR=(220-Age-RHR)*INTEN+RHR;

elseif strcmp(Gender,'Female') || strcmp(Gender,'female')

    THR=((06-0.88*Age)-RHR)*INTEN+RHR;

end

%// Create a string to display
DispMessage = sprintf('The recommended training heart rate is %0.2f\n',THR);

%// Create a message box to display the above string.
msgbox(DispMessage)
```

Here is what the prompt window looks like:

[image]

and the message displayed:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's much more than what was required. +1.

Comment: My pleasure! Welcome to the world of Matlab and strings haha have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab could not figure out what you giving as input. Correct version is:

```
 Gender=input('Please input your gender: ','s');
```

Also besides that there are more mistakes in your code which I suggest for you to fix by yourself. My less advanced version then abowe:

```
Gender=input('Please input your gender: ','s');
Age=input('Please input your age: ');
RHR=input('Please enter your resting heart rate: ');
INTEN=input('Please enter your fitness level(low,medium or high): ','s');
if strcmp(INTEN,'low')
INTENT=0.55;
elseif strcmp(INTEN,'medium')
INTEN=0.65;
else 
INTEN=0.8;
end

if strcmp(Gender,'male')|| strcmp(Gender,'Male')
THR=((220-Age)-RHR)*INTEN+RHR;
if strcmp(Gender,'female')|| strcmp(Gender,'Female')
THR=((206-0.88*Age)-RHR)*INTEN+RHR;
end

printres=['The recommended training heart rate is ',num2str(THR)];
disp(printres)
```

Comment: the result of THR is not true

Comment: fixed, have debugged it on male cases